# Задержка в конце нескольких действий

Tags: jquery

Всем привет.
В одной функции есть два действия.
В самом конце этих двух действий нужна пауза в 500 миллисекунд, чтобы в течении этого времени событие клик не работало)
Каким способом это реализовать?

```js
$(window).on('load', function () {

$('.block').on('click', function () {
$(this).toggleClass('red');
$('.block2').addClass('hide');
/*Вот здесь нужна пауза в 500 миллисекунд и чтобы во время данной паузы событие клик не работало*/
});

});
```

```css
.block{
background: gray;
text-align: center;
width: 30%;  
margin-top: 50px;
margin-left: 50px; 
font-size: 30px;
user-select: none;
}

.block2{
background: gold;
text-align: center;
width: 30%;  
margin-top: 50px;
margin-left: 50px; 
font-size: 30px;
user-select: none; 
}


.red{
 background: red; 
}

.hide{
 display:none; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="block">Кликай</div> 
  
<div class="block2">Удаление</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(window).on('load', function () {

$('.block').on('click', function () {
if ($('.block').data("disabled")!="true") {
$('.block').data("disabled","true");
$(this).toggleClass('red');
$('.block2').addClass('hide');
setTimeout(function() {$('.block').data("disabled","false");}, 500);
}
});

});
```

```css
.block{
background: gray;
text-align: center;
width: 30%;  
margin-top: 50px;
margin-left: 50px; 
font-size: 30px;
user-select: none;
}

.block2{
background: gold;
text-align: center;
width: 30%;  
margin-top: 50px;
margin-left: 50px; 
font-size: 30px;
user-select: none; 
}


.red{
 background: red; 
}

.hide{
 display:none; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="block">Кликай</div> 
  
<div class="block2">Удаление</div>
```